# Who uses the "\smile" symbol, and what for?

Tags: symbols

I am reading a textbook which uses the LaTeX `\smile` symbol (a sort of sideways parenthesis) for concatenation of lists.  I have never seen this symbol anywhere before except in the document which lists all LaTeX symbols.  It may be that this use of `\smile` for concatenation is standard, and has passed me by.  I myself either simply use + for concatenation, or if in pseudo code write it out in words.

Anyway, I'm just curious as to this use of the smile symbol.

Comment: [Cup product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product) and the [cap product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_product) use those symbols. Also, the `\frown` macro has been used as some form of [accent in math-mode](http://www.latexsearch.com/latexFacets.do?searchInput=%5Cfrown&stype=exact).

Answer (score 7):

It is very common in Mathematics, more specific in Algebraic Topology. It is used to denote the [cup product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product).

Comment: There is also the rather lazy alternative $\cup$ for this, which would *seem* to be correct based on the name.  I never got that.

Comment: @RyanReich, in old texts we can see the `cup` symbol being used to cup products. But nowadays we have this better option and `cup` is used for unions.

Comment: Thanks: cup product it is.  (My own knowledge of algebraic topology never advanced very far beyond elementary undergraduate material.)  Maybe since `\cup` is used for unions, the "cup product" should be re-named the "smile product"!

Comment: @Alasdair, in some sense, the cup product is related with a 'kind of union'.

Comment: @Sigur I see `\cup` usd in newly written documents all the time. It's the name, I believe. And lack of interest in learning of the numerous subtly different alternatives when a decent default exists. I agree that the cup, being dual to an actual intersection pairing in homology, is "a kind of union", which explains at least the shape of the symbol, if not its precise proportions.

Comment: \smile positioned on the baseline occurs also in performance scores of musical settings of poems or religious verse where it is used at the end of a line or text to denote a "carry-over" to the next line or phrase with no pause or breath.